# Conditional compilation in system header files

Tags: c++, linux, architecture, conditional-compilation

The question that how the conditional compilation in the system header files (such as `<sys/types.h>`) control the compiling process confused me for a long time
For example, here's one common typedef code fragment in `<sys/types.h>`:

```
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int int64_t;
#  elif __GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG
__extension__ typedef long long int int64_t;
#  endif
# endif
```

That said, if `__WORDSIZE == 64`, then we define the type `int64_t` as one alias of `long int`, but I wonder that where can I find the definition of `__WORDSIZE`.

- Has the macro of `__WORDSIZE` been defined statically in some file? If
  so, how does this file get generated?
- Or, we pass the preprocessor macros to the compiler?
- Or, the compiler know on what kind of machine it is running exactly? But how does it know?

After all, how can I write one header file that can achieve the following intention:

```
#if the machine is 64-bit
typedef unsigned long int KEY_TYPE
#elif the machine is 32-bit
typedef unsigned long long int KEY_TYPE
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and the system.  It (`__WORDSIZE`) may be defined by the compiler as a built-in macro (that may change depending on compiler options), or it may be in a system header.  Reading system headers is hard work at best; in general, you should not be trying to second-guess what's in them.

Note that `__WORDSIZE` is in the namespace reserved for the implementation.  The implementation may do as it likes with it as long is it works correctly.  If you tie your code to `__WORDSIZE`, you may run into problems when you change compiler versions, compiler brands, operating system versions, operating system brands.

As to how the compiler detects what system it is on: that is the compiler's problem.  It is built to generate code for a specific system (usually the host system, unless it is a cross-compiler).  The compiler is set up to know how to compile code correctly; how to create 32-bit object code or programs, and how to create 64-bit object code or programs.  It wouldn't be much use as a compiler if it did not know how to create the code correctly, would it?

You can achieve your goal with:

```
// #include <stdint.h> // C header
#include <cstdint>     // C++ analogue of <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t KEY_TYPE;
```

No conditional compilation in your code — that's the best way to write the code.

(*Caveat:* Technically, `uint64_t` is an optional type.  However, it looks like you'll have problems regardless if it is not available.)

Comment: who controls the compiler options? Do you mean that the compiler will give the __WORDSIZE different definition accordint to what kind of computer it is installed? but, how can the compiler knows the features of the machine? Does it need we give those feature option mannually? But I dont remember I do this when I install gcc compiler on my machine.

Comment: On my machines, I use GCC most often.  I can use `gcc -m64` to generate 64-bit object code and `gcc -m32` to generate 32-bit code, running the same compiler each time.  If I try to use the compiler for Mac OS X on a Linux machine, it doesn't run, nor vice versa, so yes, the compiler knows which machine type it is installed on.  A compiler that is built as a 64-bit binary won't run on a machine that only supports 32-bit binaries, either.  So, you (the person running the compiler) control the compiler options, though the compiler will have defaults that it uses if you don't override them.

Comment: By the way, I also want to know the relationship between system header files and the gcc compiler's header files. Is there any dependency relationship betweem them? and, who create the system header files? Does the process of installing the Linux OS always contains system header files creation?

Comment: GCC uses the system headers when it can, but it contains a step `fixincludes` that fixes various problems that it finds in system headers, creating its own private variant of the troublesome system header.  The system headers are delivered by the people building the system.  Some are kernel headers; some are not.  Those that are not may come with the system's C library.  Installing Linux does not necessarily install system headers.  You have to install the development system (the C compiler and related packages) to get the core headers, and specific packages to get their corresponding headers.

Answer (score 1):

To discover the gcc built-in defines (before any files are compiled) try using:

gcc -std=c++11 -E -P -v -dD temp.cpp

(temp.cpp just needs to be an empty file)

Change -std=c++11 to the standard you require.

Some of these built-in defines will be used to control the compilation of the system header files.

Some of the built-in defines are for internal (to gcc) use only.  You will need to consult gcc documentation to discover which of the built-in defines you can use in your version of the gcc.